# Sylius install: get Loggable annotation

Tags: php, git, symfony, exception, sylius

I followed this steps to install Sylius:

1. git clone git@github.com:Sylius/Sylius.git # or Sylius-Standard
2. cd Sylius # or Sylius-Standard
3. php composer.phar install
4. php app/console sylius:install

The last command is throwing in console exception:

[Gedmo\Exception\InvalidMappingException]
  Class must be annotated with Loggable annotation in order to track versioned fields in class - Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is an open issue. Check in the github section:

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/1898